# How to create a list of cards with stack view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have searched all over the internet but did not find the right content to my question.

I want to *create* a particular layout which *looks exactly like the image link* which I have posted below.

What I got after searching is only the stack view and it is not the one which I was searching for; if someone illustrates this, would be of great help. Here is the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frlEf.png) for my desired layout.

Comment: There are a lot of layouts which do not come out of the box. But when you drill down to it in the basics of layouts they are not so difficult to implement. You can have a card view inside a recycler view for the top part of it. Of course, you need to customize the cardview layout with custom drawables. Again, the bottom stack kind of layout can be achieved by using a layer list drawable based on the custom requirements

Comment: Hahaha!!! Smart Answer.

Comment: @sushant Can u help me to implement this???

Comment: What help do you need? Do you want me to code the layout for you? Have you already made any progress on this?

Comment: I have tried to do but ended up with failure, can you brief more about how to implement this i am new to android. need help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot looks more like a linear list of cropped cards, but if still want a `ViewGroup` that can layout its `Views` in stacked fashion, try using these libraries:

https://github.com/rameshvoltella/StackWidget-App-Android
https://github.com/blipinsk/FlippableStackView

Comment: Oh and I found these libraries on this http://android-arsenal.com, an incredibly great repository of useful libraries.